# Flush shared cache between integration tests

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am performing integration tests by using embedded Glassfish 3.1.2. The first thing I do in the test is to reset the database so each test have a completely fresh database to play with.

However, the problem is that the objects are persisted in the shared cache and not stored in the database. So when the next test starts it will get the old records from the cache instead of the database.

I can easily get rid of the problem by define

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

in my persistence.xml file.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void startup() throws Exception { 
                container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
                context = container.getContext();
    }

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  //Clean database before every test using dbunit
}

@Test // This is the first test, works well since the test is first in order
public final void testCreateUser() throws Exception {       
    UserService userService = (UserService) context.lookup("java:global/galleria/galleria-ejb/UserService");
    User user = new User(TEST_USER_ID, TEST_PASSWORD);
    User actualUser = userService.signupUser(user);
    assertTrue(actualUser != null);
    assertEquals(TEST_USER_ID, actualUser.getUserId());
    assertFalse(Arrays.equals(TEST_PASSWORD, actualUser.getPassword()));
    logger.info("Finished executing test method {}", testMethod.getMethodName());
}



 @Test // This is the second test, fails since the database not is clean
 public final void testCreateUser() throws Exception {      
    UserService userService = (UserService) context.lookup("java:global/galleria/galleria-ejb/UserService");
    User user = new User(TEST_USER_ID, TEST_PASSWORD);
    User actualUser = userService.signupUser(user); // FAILS since TEST_USER_ID already in cache!!

    //..
 }

@Stateless
@EJB(name = "java:global/galleria/galleria-ejb/UserService", beanInterface = UserService.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{
    @EJB
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @PermitAll
    public User signupUser(User user) throws UserException {            

        User existingUser = userRepository.findById(user.getUserId());
        if (existingUser != null)
        {
            logger.error("Attempted to create a duplicate user.");
            throw new UserException(DUPLICATE_USER);
        }

        try {
             user = userRepository.create(user);
        } catch (EntityExistsException entityExistsEx) {
            logger.error("Attempted to create a duplicate user.");
            throw new UserException(DUPLICATE_USER, entityExistsEx);
        }
        return user;
    }

        //..
}
```

However, I do not want to disable caching in persistence.xml file, since I will get performance loss later on. I only want to do it while testing. Note that I am using JTA data source here.

Any ideas?

Off topic, I am trying to learn java ee, and following the Galleria EE project and try to modify it for my needs.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching
as both JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink native api allow clearing the shared cache.  You could call this api at the start or end of your tests.